# Unquote JSON_EXTRACT value extracted from nested JSON object

Tags: mysql, json

I have a column with `json` type in MySQL database and the stored data structure is as follows:

```
table row 1:
    {
       "products":[
          {
             "price_c":"800",
             "item":"cloth"
          },
          {
             "price_f":"100",
             "item":"food"
          }
       ]
    }
table row 2:
    {
       "products":[
          {
             "price_c":"600",
             "item":"cloth"
          },
          {
             "price_f":"200",
             "item":"food"
          }
       ]
    }
```

I have been trying to extract the `price` of ass `"item":"food"` and did that with the query:

```
SELECT column->>'$**.price_f' as Price FROM table
where JSON_CONTAINS(column, '{"item":"food"}', '$.products');
```

But the problem with this approach is that it returns

```
+---------+
|  Price  |
+---------+
| ["100"] |
| ["200"] |
+---------+
```

Although I have used `->>` but still the result is not unquoted and I have figured out that it is probably due to the wildcard `$**.price`. I have tried `JSON_UNQUOTE` and it also doesn't work. How should I unquote the outputs?

Here is the [sample project in dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=618126b32099e933524c49daf8c912f4)

Comment: your query doesn return your out put https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=bf71da993819d8a4e449c36528414c9b

Comment: @nbk Oh! Thanks for noticing it. I have updated the json structure. They are in two different rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a string , so use string functions to remove the unwanted character

> ```
> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(col1->>'$**.price_f' ,'[^0-9]','') as Price FROM tab1
> where JSON_CONTAINS(col1, '{"item":"food"}', '$.products');
> ```

> ```
> | Price |
> | :---- |
> | 200   |
> | 100   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=d086a0d4e98886b29af6b81de8a13bee)*

MySql 5.7 you need to preplace them one by one. and could be done in a function

> ```
> SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(col1->>'$**.price_f' ,'[',''),']',''),'"','')   as Price FROM tab1
> where JSON_CONTAINS(col1, '{"item":"food"}', '$.products');
> ```

> ```
> | Price |
> | :---- |
> | 200   |
> | 100   |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=8eb333df559c8de0b32af78d47f41797)*

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. However, is there any workaround for MySQL 5.7?

Comment: there is nio good way for that, but i added another version